# Copy row from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one sheet to another with few conditions:
1. Start with row 1 and column 1 and match if the R1 C2 is not empty then copy the pair R1 C1 and R1 C2 and paste into the other sheet as a new row.
increment the counter for column and match R1 C1 with R1 C3 and so on.
increment the Row when the column counter reaches 10.

I tried the below code but gives compile error as Sub or function not defined.

Please help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = 2
    y = 2
    Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
        If Cells(x, y) <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) > Offset(1, 0).Row
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(erow)
        End If
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        y = y + 1
        If y = 10 Then x = x + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is ` > ` doing in `Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) > Offset(1, 0).Row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are geting that error because of `>` in `Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) > Offset(1, 0).Row`

1. Avoid the use of using `Integer` when you are working with rows. Post `excel2007`, the row count has increased and the `Integer` may not be able to handle the row number.
2. Avoid the use of `.Activate`.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

**Note**: I am demonstrating and hence I am working with the excel cells directly. But in reality, I would be using autofilter & arrays to perform this operation.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lRowInput As Long, lRowOutput As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With wsInput
        lRowInput = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRowInput
            If .Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
                For j = 3 To 10
                    lRowOutput = wsOutput.Range("A" & wsOutput.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    .Range(.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 1)).Address & _
                    "," & _
                    .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(i, j)).Address).Copy _
                    wsOutput.Range("A" & lRowOutput)
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Its only copying the R1 C1 & R1 C2. but i want to copy R1 C1 through R1 C10---and after that i want to increment the Row to R2 and copy again R2C1 through R2 C10

Comment: Your question says that you want `copy the pair R1 C1 and R1 C2` but if you want to now copy till Col 10 then change `.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2)).Copy` to `.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 10)).Copy`

Comment: No this is not i m expecting. I want to copy pair R1 C1 and R1 C2 then again R1 C1 and R1 C3 --- till R1 C1 and R1 C10

Comment: so there will be 10 new rows in sheet 2 for one single row in sheet 1

Comment: oh I see what you mean.. Gimme few mins

Comment: after that increment the Row to R2 and same procedure follows again. R2 C1 and R2 C2 till R2 C1 and R2 C10

Comment: I have updated the answer. You may have to refresh it to see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89482/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-siddharth-rout).